# Collision detection JavaScript malfunction

Tags: javascript, collision-detection

My program is a collision based game. However the collision detection function malfunctions and increases the score rapidly at random points and ends the game early even if the player is not colliding with anything. I have reviewed my code for several days and tried multiple collision detection functions but i keep getting this issue. I am making this game on code.org app lab and suspect it may possibly be on their end. But i just wanted to know if I'm missing something.
Heres a link to my program: https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/4gT5jkTadBOpofcLX__AvAeb0R3keRYLobVqNhHYaqM

```
var collectedSouls = 0;
var timer = 30;
onEvent("startBtn", "click", function(event) {
  setScreen("Gamescreen");
  playSound("Windows XP startup.mp3", false);
});
onEvent("Begin", "click", function(event) {
  onEvent("Gamescreen", "keydown", function(event) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    if (event.key == "Down") {
      y = 3;
    } else if ((event.key == "Up")) {
      y = -3;
    } else if ((event.key == "Left")) {
      x = -3;
    } else if ((event.key == "Right")) {
      x = 3;
    }
    setPosition("player", getXPosition("player") + x, getYPosition("player") + y);
    wrapAround("player");
  });
  timedLoop(1000, function() {
    setText("Timer", timer);
    timer = timer - 1;
    if (timer <= 0) {
      setScreen("GameOver");
    }
  });
});
onEvent("Begin", "click", function(event) {
  timedLoop(1, function() {
    moveObject("spirit1", randomNumber(-10, 10), randomNumber(-10, 10));
    moveObject("spirit2", randomNumber(-10, 10), randomNumber(-10, 10));
    moveObject("spirit3", randomNumber(-10, 10), randomNumber(-10, 10));
    moveObject("spirit4", randomNumber(-10, 10), randomNumber(-10, 10));
    moveObject("spirit5", randomNumber(-10, 10), randomNumber(-10, 10));
    moveObject("spirit6", randomNumber(-10, 10), randomNumber(-10, 10));
    moveObject("spirit7", randomNumber(-10, 10), randomNumber(-10, 10));
  });
});
function moveObject(object, xMove, yMove) {
  var x = getXPosition(object) + xMove;
  var y = getYPosition(object) + yMove;
  setPosition(object, x, y);
  collision(getXPosition("player"), getYPosition("player"), getProperty("player", "width"), getProperty("player", "height"), getXPosition(object), getYPosition(object), getProperty(object, "width"), getProperty(object, "height"));
  if (collision()=== true) {
    hideElement(object);
    collectedSouls = collectedSouls + 1;
    if (collectedSouls >= 7) {
        setScreen("Victory");
      }
  }
  wrapAround(object);
}
function collision(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
    w2 += x2;
    w1 += x1;
    if (x2 > w1 || x1 > w2) return false;
    h2 += y2;
    h1 += y1;
    if (y2 > h1 || y1 > h2) return false;
    return true;
}
function wrapAround(object) {
  var objx = getXPosition(object);
  var objy = getYPosition(object);
  var Width = getProperty(object, "width");
  var Height = getProperty(object, "height");
  if (objx < 0 - Width / 2) {
    objx = 320 - Width / 2;
  } else if ((objx > 320 - Width / 2)) {
    objx = 0 - Width / 2;
  } else if ((objy < 0 - Height / 2)) {
    objy = 450 - Height / 2;
  } else if ((objy > 450 - Height / 2)) {
    objy = 0 - Height / 2;
  }
  setPosition(object, objx, objy);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a full example of how to run your code? It is quite hard to follow without being able to run it or seeing which functions are being called when

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick snippet - it may help to break things up and not have everything all inline instead create variables to reference for the objects.

```
function collision(x1, y1, w1, h1, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
    w2 += x2;
    w1 += x1;
    if (x2 > w1 || x1 > w2) return false;
    h2 += y2;
    h1 += y1;
    if (y2 > h1 || y1 > h2) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Here you want to compare 2 objects like you are but keep things clean to better understand what all is happening.

Comment: I attempted to use that snippet and it still had the same issue. Here's a direct link to my program. [link](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/4gT5jkTadBOpofcLX__AvAeb0R3keRYLobVqNhHYaqM)